# Can lipo and Lithium-ion batteries be used together?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, lithium-polymer

Lithium ion batteries have high specific energy and lipo have high c rating (high power).  Is it possible to put lipo and lithium-ion batteries in parallel if they are at the same voltage and protected by charge control circuitry?  This would give you a battery that has high energy density,  but can also deliver short bursts of high power.  The lipo would charge up from the lithium ion then deliver high power when needed the way capacitors are commonly used.  It would be isolated from the circuit by transistors which would control charging and discharging.

Comment: What do you mean by "charge control circuitry"?  If you read up on battery charging you may find some versions of "charge control circuitry" very complex.  Perhaps to the extent that one may consider the batteries of different chemistry so well isolated that they are practically independent power sources.

Comment: Lithium Ion/ Polymer and LiPO are often interchanged names. which chemistry? mAh ratings and aging factor? What is the ESR in each? AS long as one doesn't change cell V with self-heating and start a thermal runaway process